# Floating spans in captions

Tags: firefox, html, floating, caption

Hi guys this is my piece of code ..

```
...
<caption>
<span class="drawicon">&nbsp;</span>
I am the Caption Text
<span style="float:right;">Extra</span>
</caption>
...
```

I'm currently don't understand why the span that floats will appear below the caption in firefox but not in other browsers.

```
 ______________________________________________________________
| [icon] I am the Caption Text                                 |
|______________________________________________________________|
                                                 |_____________|<- span that floats
```

Comment: You might just be missing a `display:block` but can't really tell without knowing how you have your `caption` styled.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the relevant CSS information as well?

The different browsers interpret the CSS Box Model differently, resulting in different decisions around how to display things. I believe Firefox interprets margins differently, but I don't know if that is affecting anything here as you haven't shown the relevant CSS.

I prefer using div's to set width and height and would switch to those here instead of spans. But review the CSS Box Model and how FF interprets it vs. other browsers.